# Retrieving email address from a globalAddressList in outlook

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

Based on the description for the [AddressEntry.Address](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.addressentry.address.aspxhttp://) Property, I expect the following to "return a String (string in C#) representing the e-mail address of the AddressEntry."

```
  Outlook.AddressList gal = Application.Session.GetGlobalAddressList();
  Outlook.AddressEntries ae = gal.AddressEntries;
  List<string> email = new List<string>();

  foreach (Outlook.AddressEntry e in ae)
  {
      email.Add(e.Address);
  }
```

Rather, the email list fills up with strings that look like...

```
"/o=companyName/ou=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/cn=Recipients/cn=firstname.lastname"
```

I would prefer it return something like....

```
firstname.lastname@mycompany.com
```

How am I using this incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `AddressEntry.Type == "EX"`, use `AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress`. Be prepared to handle nulls and exceptions.

Comment: Thanks.  Not sure how I would have come across that via the Documentation.  Correct, needed to handle nulls and catches, but still, with 1000 addresses in the global contact list, this took 2 minutes to load. Ouch!!!

Comment: Looping through thousands of entries i n GAL is never a good idea. Redemption might be a better option if you want to use a MAPI table instead.